# Where is the official Facelet VDL specification?

Tags: java, jsf, jakarta-ee, facelets, specifications

Is there a formal specification for Facelets and how they integrate with JSF? Looking through the JSF 2.2 specification, I see only a small section on Facelets in chapter 10. Information about custom tag libraries for Facelets seem specially limited, like the usage of handler-class / facelet apis. Is the formal specification limited to what is in JSF 2.2 and the Javadocs? I could not find a Facelet specific JSR either.

The best resource I could find about Facelets was: https://facelets.java.net/nonav/docs/dev/docbook.html and this does not look like a specification.

Answer (score 3):

The document you link to is the Facelets 1.0.0 specification by the creator of Facelets, Jacob Hookom.

To answer the original question you asked in the title, the official Facelets VDL specification for Facelets in JSF 2.2 is here:
https://javaserverfaces.java.net/nonav/docs/2.2/vdldocs/facelets/

That might not be what you're looking for with regards to implementation, so I suggest you try looking at the JEE6 tutorial instead.

PDF: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/javaeetutorial6.pdf

HTML (specifically, "Developing a Simple Facelets Application"):

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gipob.html

HTML (specifically, "Defining the Custom Component Tag in a Tag Library Descriptor"):

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnawn.html

And here is the JEE7 tutorial's "Introduction to Facelets":

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/doc/jsf-facelets.htm#GIEPX